# Laravel event subscriptions

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel I know that I can subscribe to an event handler like this,

```
Event::subscribe( new ProjectEventHandler );
```

in a single request I have a few models that subscribe to this handler resulting multiple events being fired so instead of one, one is fired for each subscription, is there away to check if I am already subscribed to an event?

I am basically doing some default setup for new users, so doing some in a very basic form like this,

`$project->save();
$item->save();`

In my project model I have a model event for created, in which I subscribe to an EventHandler, in my item model I also subscribe to the event handler. Thus meaning that the item events get fired twice as I am subscribed twice.

I cannot remove the subscriptions, as standalone they work fine, i.e when a user is singularly saving a project or an item on it's own.

Comment: Why not just attach listener to the events you want to listen on?

Comment: Please see further details

Comment: You should have `Event::subscribe( new ProjectEventHandler );` only once in your entire project.

Comment: You have two options: either wrap up the creation of a user in a service class, and do any set up in a method in that class. Alternatively, manually raise a new `UserCreated` event or similar, that has a listener that does anything you need to do in response to a user being created. As you are finding, you’re current approach isn’t the best way.